# Passing through current form instance to another Class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have come across an issue i'm unable to solve, i'm trying to pass through to a class an instance of the form `this`.

My code:

```
namespace newapplication
{
    public partial class FormBrowser : Form
    {
        public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
        private ChromeDriver _driver;
        private readonly FormMain _formMain;
        public static ClassProject _project;
        public static string _mode;
        private readonly string[] _sites;
        private static int counter = 0;
        private static int sitesCount = 0;
        public bool useSelenium = false;
        public bool useDebugJS = false;

        public FormBrowser(string[] sites, string mode, FormMain formMain, ClassProject project)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeBrowser(sites, project);

            _formMain = formMain;
            _mode = mode;
            _sites = sites;
            _project = project;
        }

        private FormBrowser _formBrowser;
        public class MyCustomMenuHandler : IContextMenuHandler
        {
            public void OnBeforeContextMenu(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IContextMenuParams parameters, IMenuModel model)
            {
                // Remove any existent option using the Clear method of the model.
                model.Clear();

                if (model.Count > 0)
                {
                    model.AddSeparator();
                }

                model.AddItem((CefMenuCommand)26508, "Copy text ...");
                model.AddItem((CefMenuCommand)26509, "Paste text ...");
                model.AddSeparator();
                model.AddItem((CefMenuCommand)26501, "Open chrome devtools ...");
                model.AddItem((CefMenuCommand)26502, "Open email verifier ...");
                model.AddSeparator();
                model.AddItem((CefMenuCommand)26503, "Copy current URL ...");
                model.AddSeparator();
                model.AddItem((CefMenuCommand)26504, "Save selected text to [REG] flags ...");
                model.AddItem((CefMenuCommand)26505, "Save selected text to [LAP] flags ...");
                model.AddItem((CefMenuCommand)26506, "Save selected text to email link flags ...");
                model.AddItem((CefMenuCommand)26507, "Save selected text to email link ignore flags ...");
            }

            public bool OnContextMenuCommand(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IContextMenuParams parameters, CefMenuCommand commandId, CefEventFlags eventFlags)
            {
                if (commandId == (CefMenuCommand)26501)
                {
                    browser.GetHost().ShowDevTools();
                    return true;
                }

                if (commandId == (CefMenuCommand)26502)
                {
                    FormEmailsActivation fea = new FormEmailsActivation(_formBrowser);
                    fea.Show();
                    return true;
                }

                if (commandId == (CefMenuCommand)26503)
                {
                    if (_mode == "MODE_LAP")
                    {
                        UpdatePostedLink(_project, _formBrowser);
                    }
                    else
```

I'm trying to pass through an instance of the current form:

```
private FormBrowser _formBrowser;
```

to this class:

```
public class MyCustomMenuHandler : IContextMenuHandler
```

I thought i could do:

```
public class MyCustomMenuHandler : IContextMenuHandler(_formBrowser)
```

But this is just showing a lot of errors I cannot even list (it was just an attempt to try something)

I am totally stumped on how to get the form instance through so it's value won't be null.

The answer is probably staring me in the face, any tips on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not following.  Is this Windows Forms?  If so (or if it's something else), please tag the question correctly.  Your _I thought i could do_ code makes no sense.  What were you trying to do with that code?  The code you show ends with a line that says `else`; is that where you wanted to stop?  How do you associate your context menu handler instance with whatever you want it to handle (I'm guessing the form).  As a guess, wherever you do that, you will need to pass the form in as part of the constructor - but, as I said, I'm not following

Comment: The interface is not a method, you can not use it like that and pass argument.

Comment: In your `FormBrowser` class, you have `private FormBrowser _formBrowser;`  What is that supposed to represent?  Is it a different instance of the class than `this`?

Comment: I only posted the relevant code, that's why it cuts off abruptly.

Comment: ```private static FormBrowser _formBrowser;``` is the same as ```this``` you are right, i don't know what i was thinking there.

Comment: As @Flydog57 says at the end of the first comment: probably you need to pass the instance of `FormBrowser` via a constructor to `MyCustomMenuHandler`, such as: `var handler = new MyCustomMenuHandler(this);`.  If such a constructor doesn't exist, you could create one.  If this isn't helping, you might need to show more relevant code of the `MyCustomMenuHandler` class, such as the code expecting to use the instance of `FormBrowser`.

Comment: You've tagged it WinForms.  Thanks.  But, after some spelunking, it seems like you are using CefSharp (I think).  If so, tag that as well.  The point of the tags is two-fold: 1) it is additional information about the technologies you are using, but also 2) a good tag will attract experts in the relevant technologies.  If someone is _watching_ CefSharp, then he/she might be an expert at context menu handlers. Selected code is good, but it needs to be reasonable, preferably as a [mcve].  Ending with a hanging `else` is pretty useless.

Comment: You still have `private FormBrowser _formBrowser;` in your post.  So you are still _thinking_ whatever it was you were thinking.  And, that's very likely separate from `this` unless you initialize it to `this` (which you don't in your "relevant code").

Comment: It's not possible to pass instances to classes; classes aren't "things" that can receive a "thing"

Comment: `public class MyCustomMenuHandler : IContextMenuHandler(_formBrowser)` is definitely invalid syntax since you are declaring a type and all the incoming data is specified in the constructor and not in the type declation.

Answer (score 1):

Your "thought I could do" is close... You just need to overload the class you are trying to create so it accepts a PARAMETER of the incoming form you are trying to pass it.

```
public class MyCustomMenuHandler : IContextMenuHandler
{

   private FormBrowser _formBrowser;

   public MyCustomMenuHandler()
   {
      // whatever code if no form parameter
   }

   public MyCustomerMenuHandler(FormBrowser incomingForm )
   {
      // Now, you have the form to do whatever you need to.
      _formBrowser = incomingForm;
   }
}
```

Then, just call with the parameter

```
var mnuHndlr = new MyCustomMenuHandler( theOriginalFormBrowserObjectVariable );
```

And in your case, yes, you CAN pass in with "this"

```
var mnuHndlr = new MyCustomMenuHandler( this );
```

Comment: Thank you DRapp it is definately a lot clearer visually.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple. Follow this skeleton code:

```
public class FormBrowser : Form
{
    MyCustomMenuHandler menuHandler;

    void InitializeComponent()
    {
        menuHandler = new MyCustomMenuHandler(this);
    }
}

public class MyCustomMenuHandler : IContextMenuHandler
{
    public MyCustomMenuHandler(FormBrowser formBrwoser)
    {
        Browser = formBrowser;
    }

    public FormBrowser Browser { get; }
}
```

All information needed to construct a `MyCustomMenuHandler` should be supplied on its constructor. Use the `this` keyword to get a reference to the current form in any method of `FormBrowser`.

Comment: Thank you very much guys, It is a lot clearer now, and I fixed the issue by looking at the above code. Thanks again.